# including url parameters in if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, if-statement

I'm trying to have different parts of my layout included in different pages, I currently have this:

```
- if %w(/ /news).include? request.fullpath
  = yield      

- unless %w(/ /news).include? request.fullpath
```

which means when the URL is the homepage or the news page, the content is shown. I need this to include when there is a parameter in the homepage URL eg `/?campaign=test` I've tried a few things but can't get it to recognise separate parameters.

**Answer:**

```
- if params[:controller] == 'application' && params[:action] == 'index' && params[:campaign].present?
  = yield      

- elsif params[:controller] == 'application' && params[:action] == 'index'
  = yield

- else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of request fullpath you can take params
like

```
  if params[:controller] == 'news'
  if params[:action] == 'smth'
  if params[:campaign] == 'test'
```

in your conditions.

UPD

```
- if params[:controller] == 'homepage'
  = 'This is homepage'
- if params[:controller] == 'homepage' && params[:campaign].present?
  = 'this homepage is with campaign.'
```

This definetely should work.

Comment: but i need it to be whenever there is a campaign on the end of the home page, meaning any campaign would work

Comment: @user1738017 SO just use if params[:campaign].any? or if params[:campaign].present?

Comment: i only want it if it's present on the home page, not if its present on any page

Comment: @user1738017, you're kidding me ? it is as easy as adding another condition, let say your homepage controller called 'homepage_controller.rb', so it will be if params[:controller] =='homepage' && params[:campaign].present?

Comment: i've added this to the end of what i was already using `|| params[:controller]=='application' && params[:campaign].present?` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user1738017 what do you mean saying "doesn't work"? can you check the values for your variables, e.g. <%= debug params %>?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20699/discussion-between-pavel-s-and-user1738017)

Comment: i mean when i go to `/?campaign=anything`, it still includes the rest of the content after the `unless` statement

Comment: I've updated the answer, can you update question with the code you have and also show your `= debug params`