# How to render different divs using conditional in a html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I am trying to render different divs in a `.html.erb` file if the url contains certain strings:

```
<% if request.path_info.include?('abc') %>
  <div>ABC</div>
<% elsif request.path_info.include?('xyz')  %>
  <div>XYZ</div>
<% end %>
```

I found the following code. I tried that solution but it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[If URL contains string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480223/if-url-contains-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
The error that is giving me as is follows:

Showing /Users/etc/...../something.html.erb where line #28 raised:

undefined local variable or method `request' for #<#
<Class:>:>
Did you mean?  require
Extracted source (around line #14):
12
13
14
15
16
17

      </div>

      <% if request.path_info.include?('abc') %>
        <div>ABC</div>
      <% elsif request.path_info.include?('xyz')  %>
        <div>XYZ</div>

Rails.root: /Users/etc/....something
```

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I updated the description to include the error above. Thanks!

Comment: You are using Rails?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: can you add the full error stack from log? I don't see any wrong code.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - above is the whole log showing in the browser

Comment: The view should have the `request` object access.

Comment: Why do not you better use controller_name or action_name instead of path_info? These variables return the name of the controller and action respectively, which could be used for what you want

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method that calls `something.html.erb` you need to make `request` an object. We'll need to see your controller code, but try something like below:

```
def something
  @request = request
end
```

From there you can access it in your erb like:

```
<% if @request.path_info.include?('abc') %>
```